# Create dictionary from multiple lists (lists of strings, list of lists)

Tags: list, python-3.x, dictionary, zip

I have several lists of the same length that I want to combine into a "master dictionary". Most consist of strings, while one is a list of lists. E.g.

```
directories = ['\\folder1', '\\folder2', '\\folder3']
tables = ['ABC', 'ABC', 'XYZ']
cohort = ['IN', 'OUT', 'IN']
variables = [[var1, var2, var3], [var1, var2, var3, var4, var5], [var1, var2]]
```

I would like the output to be:

```
dictionary = {'\\folder1': ('ABC', 'IN', [var1, var2, var3]),
              '\\folder2': ('ABC', 'OUT', [var1, var2, var3, var, var5]),
              '\\folder3': ('XYZ', 'IN', [var1, var2])}
```

I have tried, but do not want (b/c it creates some complex nested tuples):

```
dictionary = dict(zip(directories, zip(tables, zip(cohort, variables))))
```

Comment: Your `dictionary` is not valid: you define the `'IN'` key twice. So you cannot construct such a dictionary.

Comment: Is `'ABC', 'IN', [var1, var2, var3]` supposed to be a tuple? Otherwise that isn't a valid dictionary. If so then you have 1 too many `zip`, `d = dict(zip(directories, zip(tables, cohort, variables)))`

Comment: I want the keys to come from the list "directories". The other three lists: tables, cohort, variables should all be values (and therefore, can be non-unique). ('ABC', 'IN', [var1, var2, var3) is meant to be a tuple - thanks for pointing that out - I will edit!

Comment: Just tried  your solution, Steven. It works now - thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, Steven, for the answer to this question:

```
d = dict(zip(directories, zip(tables, cohort, variables)))
```